# Problem with Cortez wallet

Tags: wallets

I have a problem with Cortez wallet: I'm trying to transfet my XTZ to another address, but if I put my whole balance, at the moment when the fee is calculated I get an error message (com.android.volleyServerError), I have to remove the decimal to make it work, and at that point the calculated fee is not sbutracted, but added inb the final amount olf the transfer.

Example, let's say my balance is 100.333, if I try to transfer the whole amount I get the error message, if I try to transfer only 100, a fee of 0..001 is calculated, and I get "pay 100.001" on the transfer button.

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to minus the fee from the whole amount.

There is no fixed fees because we designed it to always calculate the lowest fees after you put the amount to transfer. The fees can depend on the amount or the current blockchain protocol.

It makes it difficult for a user to minus the exact amount to transfer the whole balance. It's a next feature to implement properly.